# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets'. How to solve this?

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow-datasets, modulenotfounderror

I'm new to Python and am usually running Spyder or VS Code. I am running a script right now that gives me the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets'.

I can see on my `pip list` that I have tensorflow ver. 2.4.0 and tensorflow_datasets ver. 4.2.0.
The location of `tensorflow` is:

```
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

And the location of `tensorflow_datasets` is:

```
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Maybe it has something to do with the location/directory? Since I am using Spyder and VS Code through Anaconda.

I am running macOS Big Sur 11.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IDE or Jupyter?

IDE:

Choose Anacondna as your default environment, Mac is running on Python 2 by default.

Jupyter:
[Kernel>Change Kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t1gq.png)

Pycharm:
[Bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivsv3.png)

VS Code:
[Bottom left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dml7i.png)

Comment: By default I am using an environment in anaconda with Python 3.8. I tried with another environment running Python 3.7, none of which worked. Note that tensorflow module works, but not tensorflow_datasets.
This is the path to tensorflow:
`'/Users/kalleleander/opt/anaconda3/envs/new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow'`

Comment: can you check to be sure you are using the right env: `which python`

Comment: Also, check if you do install `tensorflow_dataset`, otherwise install it: `pip install tensorflow_datasets`

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of your VS Code setup? 

I would also recommend you to set anaconda as your default environment, as @antoine mentioned it could be that you may of have installed tensorflow_dataset on a different environment.
http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/
Link on how to set environment

Comment: Attempted to install dataset on a fresh environment got this error:

ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

tensorflow-metadata 0.26.0 requires absl-py<0.11,>=0.9, but you'll have absl-py 0.11.0 which is incompatible.

did you get it when you were installing?

Comment: `/Users/kalleleander/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` this is my default env

Comment: try following: 
1. python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
2. pip install tensorflow_datasets --use-feature=2020-resolver

Comment: It seems that I can find tensorflow_datasets in the site-packages under my `Library/Python.framework` but not under the `anaconda3/envs/new/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

Comment: @AkmalSoliev when I run the second command you gave me it just says "requirement already satisfied" : `Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos<2,>=1.52.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow-metadata->tensorflow_datasets) (1.52.0)`

Comment: @kalleleander okay you need to run anaconda bash and install there.... wait did you use just pip install or pip3 install?

Comment: pip install only, I've tried pip3 install now, did not make a difference

Comment: just attempted to recreate your problem, everything works fine on my end, using the same system as you do. have you installed both modules with pip3 install? what is the error?

Comment: Different installations using conda, pip and pip3 might have messed something up. Furthermore, when I do `which python` it tell me I am in the anaconda environment, but then when I try to install tensorflow_datasets, it tells me that it is already installed, but not in the anaconda environment, just in the Python.framework in the /Library/Frameworks